# php to csv attachment - wordpress/woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, email, csv, woocommerce

I'm trying take this code, and make it generate / attach a CSV.

I have gathered from similar questions that i'll need some strings like;

```
$csvString = "billing_first_name, billing_last_name, billing_phone, billing_phone, order, Product, Quantity, Price";
$attachment = chunk_split(base64_encode($csvString));
```

Once i've got my attachment generated, how to i add it to the email?

Am i correct in assuming it needs to be wrapped in php do_action() ?

This is the email template:

```
<?php
/**
 * Admin new order email
 *
 * @author WooThemes
 * @package WooCommerce/Templates/Emails/HTML
 * @version 2.0.0
 */
if ( ! defined( 'ABSPATH' ) ) exit; // Exit if accessed directly ?>

<?php do_action( 'woocommerce_email_header', $email_heading ); ?>

<p><?php printf( __( 'You have received an order from %s. Their order is as follows:', 'woocommerce' ), $order->billing_first_name . ' ' . $order->billing_last_name ); ?></p>

<?php do_action( 'woocommerce_email_before_order_table', $order, true, false ); ?>

<h2><a href="<?php echo admin_url( 'post.php?post=' . $order->id . '&action=edit' ); ?>"><?php printf( __( 'Order: %s', 'woocommerce'), $order->get_order_number() ); ?></a> (<?php printf( '<time datetime="%s">%s</time>', date_i18n( 'c', strtotime( $order->order_date ) ), date_i18n( wc_date_format(), strtotime( $order->order_date ) ) ); ?>)</h2>

<table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="6" style="width: 100%; border: 1px solid #eee;" border="1" bordercolor="#eee">
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th scope="col" style="text-align:left; border: 1px solid #eee;"><?php _e( 'Product', 'woocommerce' ); ?></th>
        <th scope="col" style="text-align:left; border: 1px solid #eee;"><?php _e( 'Quantity', 'woocommerce' ); ?></th>
        <th scope="col" style="text-align:left; border: 1px solid #eee;"><?php _e( 'Price', 'woocommerce' ); ?></th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
    <?php echo $order->email_order_items_table( false, true ); ?>
</tbody>
<tfoot>
    <?php
        if ( $totals = $order->get_order_item_totals() ) {
            $i = 0;
            foreach ( $totals as $total ) {
                $i++;
                ?><tr>
                    <th scope="row" colspan="2" style="text-align:left; border: 1px solid #eee; <?php if ( $i == 1 ) echo 'border-top-width: 4px;'; ?>"><?php echo $total['label']; ?></th>
                    <td style="text-align:left; border: 1px solid #eee; <?php if ( $i == 1 ) echo 'border-top-width: 4px;'; ?>"><?php echo $total['value']; ?></td>
                </tr><?php
            }
        }
    ?>
</tfoot>
</table>

<?php do_action( 'woocommerce_email_after_order_table', $order, true, false ); ?>

<?php do_action( 'woocommerce_email_order_meta', $order, true, false ); ?>

<h2><?php _e( 'Customer details', 'woocommerce' ); ?></h2>

<?php if ( $order->billing_email ) : ?>
<p><strong><?php _e( 'Email:', 'woocommerce' ); ?></strong> <?php echo $order->billing_email; ?></p>
<?php endif; ?>
<?php if ( $order->billing_phone ) : ?>
<p><strong><?php _e( 'Tel:', 'woocommerce' ); ?></strong> <?php echo $order->billing_phone; ?></p>
<?php endif; ?>

<?php wc_get_template( 'emails/email-addresses.php', array( 'order' => $order ) ); ?>

<?php do_action( 'woocommerce_email_footer' ); ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe you have to send your CSV file as an attachment in the new order email and you actually have nothing to do in the email template for this. You can use a WooCommerce filter for email attachments -

```
 add_filter( 'woocommerce_email_attachments', 'send_your_attachment', 10, 3);

    function send_your_attachment ( $attachments, $email_type , $order ) {
        $email_types = array( 'new_order' ); //can add more email types

        if( isset( $email_type ) && in_array ( $email_type, $email_types ) ) {
            $attachments[] = '/path to your attachment/example.csv';
        }

        return $attachments;
    }
```

Hope this helps.